# UNNEST Operator in bigquery: strange behaviour when aggregating results

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to understand how the UNNEST operator works over a public database from Google which store [CRUX data](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=chrome-ux-report) (Chrome UX Report).

At this [page](https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report-bigquery/) where some examples are provided.

I could understand the following:

- the sum of all the densities gives 1 (or the 100%)
- densities are of three types (phone, tablet, desktop)
- the bin start and end do slice the data when used

The article provides some example where the UNNEST operator is used, which expands the flatten the innermost arrays, thus making accessible for grouping operations too.

So a query like the below

```
SELECT
  SUM(fcp.density) AS fast_fcp
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.all.201809`,
  UNNEST(first_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS fcp
WHERE
  origin = 'https://developers.google.com'
```

returns the sum all all the FCP densities, a value of 0.999999.

I would have expected a second SUM over a second UNNESTED operator to work similarly; however, when I use two fields and do a sum something strange happen.

For instance the following

```
SELECT
  SUM(fcp.density) AS fast_fcp,
  SUM(lcp.density) AS fast_lcp
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.all.201809`,
  UNNEST(first_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS fcp
  UNNEST(largest_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS lcp
WHERE
  origin = 'https://developers.google.com'
```

produces something like

```
Row f0_ f1_ 
1   393.12850000000896 352.06599999922156
```

The strange thing is that if the aggregation is not used, the unnest operators work as intended and columns are expanded in columns as intended.

Can somebody help me to understand what is happening behind the door and how I could obtain the sum over a range of fields.

e.g.

```
Site;fcp;cls;fid
https://developers.google.com;0.4;0.2;0.1
https://www.google.com;0.1;0.4;0.3
```

The end goal will be select an underlying bracket of start-end value to find out the "good" sites, but I need to nail it down the why the above is not working first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Andriy M's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/298421/237455) does a good job of describing how `UNNEST` works. I'll add more context behind the CrUX dataset and how you could get the answer you're looking for.

If you're interested in analyzing the histograms to find the percent of "fast" experiences for each metric, you could skip the `UNNEST` approach entirely by using the `materialized` dataset. For example:

```sql
SELECT
  fast_fcp,
  fast_lcp
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.materialized.metrics_summary`
WHERE
  date = '2021-07-01' AND
  origin = 'https://developers.google.com'
```

Results:

```
fast_fcp    fast_lcp
0.6843      0.7234
```

Query stats: `0.6 sec elapsed, 9.3 MB processed`

The [`materialized.metrics_summary`](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=chrome-ux-report&d=materialized&t=metrics_summary&page=table) table is pre-processed according to the subjective "fast" thresholds set by the Chrome team. The query that generates this table is saved to the [`materialized.metrics_query`](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=chrome-ux-report&d=materialized&t=metrics_query&page=table) view. In it, you can see how the underlying `UNNEST`s work:

```sql
WITH fcp AS (
SELECT
  yyyymm,
  origin,
  ROUND(SUM(IF(bin.start < 1800, bin.density, 0)), 4) AS fast
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.experimental.global`
LEFT JOIN
  UNNEST(first_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE
  yyyymm = @yyyymm AND
  bin IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  yyyymm,
  origin
),
lcp AS (
SELECT
  yyyymm,
  origin,
  ROUND(SUM(IF(bin.start < 2500, bin.density, 0)), 4) AS fast
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.experimental.global`
LEFT JOIN
  UNNEST(largest_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE
  yyyymm = @yyyymm AND
  bin IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  yyyymm,
  origin
)
```

Each metric is aggregated in its own separate part of the `WITH` statement, which is output in the subsequent `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT
  yyyymm,
  origin,
  fcp.fast AS fast_fcp,
  lcp.fast AS fast_lcp
FROM
  fcp
LEFT JOIN
  lcp
USING
  (yyyymm, origin)
```

*(Simplified to omit unrelated metrics to this question)*

Using that `UNNEST` approach, here's how I'd write a query that calculates the fast FCP and LCP for a given origin:

```sql
WITH fcp AS (
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(IF(bin.start < 1800, bin.density, 0)), 4) AS fast
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.all.202107`,
  UNNEST(first_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE
  origin = 'https://developers.google.com'
),
lcp AS (
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(IF(bin.start < 2500, bin.density, 0)), 4) AS fast
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.all.202107`,
  UNNEST(largest_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE
  origin = 'https://developers.google.com'
)

SELECT
  fcp.fast AS fast_fcp,
  lcp.fast AS fast_lcp
FROM
  fcp,
  lcp
```

Results:

```
fast_fcp    fast_lcp
0.6843      0.7234
```

Query stats: `0.7 sec elapsed, 143.4 GB processed`

So it produces identical results as the `materialized.metrics_summary` table, but it consumes 15000x more data. This is because querying `all.202107` requires processing the entire table, even though we're only interested in a single origin.

Let's rewrite the query a bit to use the same [`experimental.global`](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=chrome-ux-report&d=experimental&t=global&page=table) table as the materialized view. This table is a partitioned and clustered version of the `all` dataset. The partitioning by `yyyymm` means that BigQuery never processes data outside of the `202107` release and the clustering by `origin` means that BigQuery can stop processing once it finds the origin we're looking for.

```sql
WITH fcp AS (
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(IF(bin.start < 1800, bin.density, 0)), 4) AS fast
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.experimental.global`,
  UNNEST(first_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE
  yyyymm = 202107 AND
  origin = 'https://developers.google.com'
),
lcp AS (
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(IF(bin.start < 2500, bin.density, 0)), 4) AS fast
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.experimental.global`,
  UNNEST(largest_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS bin
WHERE
  yyyymm = 202107 AND
  origin = 'https://developers.google.com'
)

SELECT
  fcp.fast AS fast_fcp,
  lcp.fast AS fast_lcp
FROM
  fcp,
  lcp
```

Results:

```
fast_fcp    fast_lcp
0.6843      0.7234
```

Query stats: `0.7 sec elapsed, 63.9 MB processed`

Same result, many fewer bytes processed, but still not as simple or cheap as the materialized dataset.

I know this is a long answer, but hopefully it convinces you to use the `materialized` dataset when relying on standard fast/slow thresholds, or fall back to the `experimental.global` dataset when you need custom thresholds.

Comment: thank you very much for your time in enlightening this. I have noticed the materialised table, and at some point I did start using it. But due to my previous attempts, the allowance was finished so couldn't really explore that much.

Comment: any chance to clarify the following? I can understand that a site might not have a FID measure because of it being very traditional and not "interactive", but what about FCP being null. That one I can't explain at all. So if I want to get a top 100 good sites, how can I discern? Would you just exclude FID, FCP, CLS  that is NULL?

Comment: FCP should never be null; it's actually the only metric required to exist in the dataset. So if you see that again please report it at https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chrome-ux-report and include your query.

Comment: Hi Rick, fcp by and large is always there; my apologies. Missing details are for the other metrics like CLS, FID etc. Also, any chance to get avg_* renamed into improve_* .... that avg is so deceptive. Till today I thought it was doing the average between the 3 values, but that's not the case.

Comment: Oh, yeah I can see how that'd be confusing. Thanks for the feedback. We try not to change the schema too often because it breaks old/automated queries so I'd like to see if this is something we could clarify in the documentation instead.

Answer (score 1):

`UNNEST` produces a row set, much like reading a regular table does. Two `UNNEST` calls give you two row sets.  You are not providing any joining condition to match those two row sets.  That means that they are *cross-joined* and you get the number of rows from one `UNNEST` multiplied by the number of rows from the other.  The `FROM` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause, meaning the cross-join happens before the aggregation.  Therefore, both `SUM` calls end up aggregating the multiple duplicates generated by the cross-join, which understandably gives you the results you did not expect.

You need to aggregate the two `UNNEST`s separately from each other.  I am not very familiar with the BigQuery syntax but presumably something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(fcp.density) FROM UNNEST(  first_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS fcp) AS fast_fcp,
  (SELECT SUM(lcp.density) FROM UNNEST(largest_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) AS lcp) AS fast_lcp
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.all.201809`
WHERE
  origin = 'https://developers.google.com'
;
```

Comment: thanks so much for your time in pointing me in the right direction. I have probably been taken off-road by the formatted output I was shown (the two unnest on the same horizontal flat view.